# Execute condition in for-each loop only once (break for-each) in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm very new to XSLT and have this problem. I have found many posts and material that there is no way of breaking for-each loop in XSLT and variables cannot be changed after you declare them, but I couldn't find the solution to my problem. If there is one already answered, please provide a link.

I want to check if in a given node-set exists at least one element that contains a specific value. If it does, I want to create an element with an attribute ONLY ONCE in the transform.

```
<xsl:variable name="name" select="$path/to/something"/>
    <xsl:if test="count($name) > 0">
        <xsl:for-each select="$name">
            <xsl:if test="ctvf:trim(./@name) = 'P'">
                <name>
                    <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="ctvf:trim(./@name)"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </name>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
```

Currently if condition check is met `<xsl:if test="ctvf:trim(./@name) = 'P'">` more than once, it creates several the same elements, I only need to create that element once.

**Sample XML**

```
<names>
    <name name="P"></name>
    <name name="B"></name>
    <name name="A"></name>
    <name name="P"></name>
</names>
```

**Expected output**

```
<name Name="P"></name>
```

**Current Output**

```
<name Name="P"></name>
<name Name="P"></name>
```

**What would be simple solution to this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to loop all elements and check weather it contains specific
>   value, if it does I want to create an element with attribute. But I
>   want to create element with that attribute only once, regardless if
>   loop continues and more conditions are met afterwards.

Restate your problem as follows:

*I want to check if in a given node-set exists at least one element that contains a specific value. If it does, I want to create an element with an attribute.*

Which, after adjusting your example,  would probably look something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="name" select="$path/to/something"/>
<xsl:if test="$name[ctvf:trim(@name) = 'P']">
    <name Name="P"/>
</xsl:if>
```

---

### Added:

To demonstrate, consider the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/names">
    <xsl:if test="name[@name = 'P']">
        <name Name="P"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name Name="P"/>
```

Applied to this example:

```
<names>
    <name name="X"></name>
    <name name="B"></name>
    <name name="A"></name>
    <name name="Y"></name>
</names>
```

the result will be empty.

Another way to achieve the same thing would be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="name[@name = 'P'][1]">
    <name Name="P"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @bigneo I am afraid you misunderstood me. I didn't mean to correct your question. I meant to say that the answer will be found by changing the way you look at the problem. If you think that the above does not return the correct result, then please provide an example of XML input and the expected output.

Comment: I have edited question with samples you asked, while I'm still trying to understand your answer. As I said - completely new to XSLT.

Comment: @bigneo I have added two demos to my answer.